# Will EC2 server instance autoscale

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability, autoscaling

Say I have a video streaming app on a ec2 medium server instance, and if concurrent users are too many, will the ec2 automatically provide additional resources for handle any number of users? if not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Not by default but it will if you set it up to autoscale - but you'll have to set that up as there's a cost implication and you need to tell it how you want it to work.

Comment: 1. If we have autoscale, a single ec2 instance will be suffice? 2. If we do not have autoscale, am I right that storage and network will scale automatically, but not processing power?

Comment: 1. How could we know? *You* need to do your own load testing. 2. No, network and storage do not scale automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. An ec2 instance is just a virtual server. If you want to use autoscaling you have to set it up using the facilities AWS provides.

AWS autoscaling scales horizontally, adding servers, rather than to larger server instances. You can scale vertically, replacing your instance with a larger one, but you will have downtime and will have to work out how to do it yourself. The implication of this is that your data must be accessible to multiple machines, ie via [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), or a server running NFS or another file sharing system than you set up manually, rather than on an EBS volume. EBS volumes can only be attached to one instance at a time.

In particular you'll want to look at [autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) and [elastic load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). Teaching you AWS is out of scope of this reply, so you need to either learn it using the resources available or hire someone who already knows how to do it.